# Why can not I properly center text inside of adjacent divs

Tags: html, css

I was trying to center text in two adjacent `divs` and I can not understand what I am doing wrong.

Basically I have 2 `divs` each taken 50% of the window. The first div contains an image (which I successfully centered) and I am trying to center the text in the second div. So here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/fzyp7/) and I am using the following css:

```
.thumbnail-descr{
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 26pt;
    color: #bbb;
}
```

There is no point of having original DOM structure or CSS (the main thing is to have 2 `divs` taking all the width and one has a centered image another one has a text. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from the example is that you want to vertically center "Descr". There are several tricks to do that:

- Adjust the padding and use box-sizing border-box to have better control of the height.
- Use flexbox (still not broadly available): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes
- If you know before hand that you'll have only one line of text you can use `line-height`.
- (See the update for another option)

For example see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/diegof79/M4fKM/):

```
.square{
  width: 45%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px dotted #ddd;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

But take a few things into account:

- This will work only if you have one line of text, because on text wrap it will be broken.
- This is not the normal use of line height, it's taking advantage of a side effect: text is vertically centered to the line-height.
- This trick is used by some CSS frameworks (ie Bootstrap) to center the text on some components.

**Update**

I forgot another option, since you have one div inside the other you can use `position: relative` on the parent, and use absolute position for the child using `top: 50%` and a negative top margin. You'll need to setup the top margin to the half of the child height. (that's how modals are usually centered):

```
.square { position: relative; /*..*/ }
.thumbnail-descr{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  /*...*/
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/diegof79/M4fKM/1/

Also you asked why your solution is not working... this can help to understand the reasons: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: Do you have any idea how to center text horizontally as well?

Comment: If you use the `position:absolute` trick... add `width:100%` to `.thumbnail-descr` and `text-align:center`

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding to giving you the solution, you could have he exact same result with a lot less code, giving so many classes for so little content can only lead to huge code.

The span class you are giving the text-align:center, doesn't fill up the whole width of the parent, so, where would it center the text since its width is equal to the text?

You can either put a 'text-align:center" to the span's parent, the square class, but I would use a different approach in general.

Comment: I assumed that this can be done with much less code, therefore I told this in the last sentence. Due to my lack of knowledge this is the first approach I came up with, so if you know better approach - can you please share it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need a span.
If you remove span tag and use same css for the div styles, or simply ad a span class name to a your div class name- works perfectly.

Comment: No, it does not work perfectly. Here is what happened: http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/fzyp7/4/.

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue happen because the width in the description div
Try this suggestion:

warp the  with div, the div will use thumbnail-descr class

```
<div class='square'>
        <div class="thumbnail-descr"><span>Descr</span><div>
    </div>
```

Update the thumbnail-descr

```
.thumbnail-descr{
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 10px;
    background-color:red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 26pt;
    color: #bbb;
    width:100%;
}
```

hope this help

Comment: Thanks for looking into the problem. Actually it did not done what I was hoping for. After applying your changes it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/fzyp7/6/

Comment: The problem is the text is not centered, isn't it? you can remove the background color, i use the backgrund-color to debug the size of class thumbnail-descr

Comment: size = width, sorry for the confusion in above comment. "debug the width..."

Comment: There is no problem with centered text in your example. The problem is that the second div is not on the same level as the first div. (it is much lower than the first one)

Comment: @SalvadorDali pls check my fiddle, it has been updated. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyanos2005/K45tL/1/)

Comment: could you provide an image the result that you expected? i am curious lol

Comment: Diego has the example of what I am expecting: http://jsfiddle.net/diegof79/M4fKM/1/